# Does mysql service restart automatically in ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

So i just set up a linux server for the backend of an  application. My nodejs app uses mysql database so i installed it with the following command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

With the command:

```
service mysql status
```

I can see that mysql server is running.

Now the question is , if i restart the server will the service automatically start or do i have to restart it?
And if i have to restart it how do i do it, as i dont recall starting the service before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should automatically restart the MySQL process, yes